# How to convert from ByteString to Instance of a class?

Tags: scala, akka

I used akka streams to process events and kept them in file. The code looks like

```
def process(file: File, resultFile: File): Future[IOResult] = {
    val source: Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(file.toURI))
    val sink: Sink[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = FileIO.toPath(Paths.get(resultFile.toURI))
    source
      .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString(System.lineSeparator), maximumFrameLength = 82, allowTruncation = true))
      .map(_.utf8String.split(","))
      .map(LineEvent(_))
      .map(lineEvent => ByteString(lineEvent.toString.getBytes))
      .runWith(sink)
  }
```

The `LineEvent` looks like

```
case object LineEvent {
  def apply(lineElements: Array[String]): LineEvent = {
    print(s"received: $lineElements")
    // TODO: validate the lineElements to verify the length correctness
    val eventUtcTime: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.parse(lineElements(1)), ZoneId.of("UTC"))
    val event: LineEvent = new LineEvent(lineElements(0), eventUtcTime, lineElements(2), lineElements(3).toLong, lineElements(4).toLong, lineElements(5).toInt, lineElements(6))
    event
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val line = "219.108.78.45,2016-07-01T16:28:47.374,GET,0,500409,403,https://www.HkwLhe.gov"
    LineEvent(line.split(","))
  }
}

case class LineEvent(ipAddress: String, eventTime: ZonedDateTime, httpMethod: String, uploadedBytes: Long, downloadedBytes: Long, httpStatus: Int, url: String)
```

When I run `process(csvFile, resultFile)`, it serializes the data on the file.

Now I want to read them back from `serialized` version to `LineEvent` instances. What I have is

```
def processSerialized(file: File): Future[Done] = {
    val source: Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(file.toURI))
    source
      .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString(System.lineSeparator), maximumFrameLength = 82, allowTruncation = true))
      .map(_.utf8String)
      .runForeach(println)
  }
```

when I run it

```
  processSerialized(new File("/Users/harit/Downloads/tmp/input-0.ser"))
```

I see

```
[B@461c868e
[B@43904f4e
[B@37808d5a
[B@1c259445
[B@3e2f59b9
[B@7f849b0d
```

How can I convert them back to `LineEvent`?

Comment: You might consider this: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/serialization.html. ProtoBuf generally has a much better performance than Java serialization, by the way.

Comment: You're already instantiating `LineEvent`s from strings in `process`: `.map(_.utf8String.split(",").map(LineEvent(_))`; shouldn't it also work in `processSerialized`?